# MySQL - Large table calculate vehicle average speeds

Tags: mysql, math, geo

I have a large table with the following structure:

| dt | veh_id | lat | long |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-14 13:00:00 | 123456ABC | 26.56602763823091 | 2.937412284992731 |
| 2021-01-14 13:00:00 | 1762GH | 26.56602763823091 | 2.937412284992731 |
| 2021-01-14 13:00:00 | 189725FT | 26.56602763823091 | 2.937412284992731 |
| 2021-01-14 13:52:07 | 123456ABC | 27.03312220493411 | 2.6008171450629343 |
| 2021-01-14 14:02:27 | 123456ABC | 27.195391148992073 | 2.490953866466876 |

What I would like to calculate (if possible) is the additional rows based on the same vehicle ID travelling.

| dt | veh_id | lat | long | Time | Distance (Miles) | Speed (MPH) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-14 13:00:00 | 123456ABC | 26.56602763823091 | 2.937412284992731 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-14 13:00:00 | 1762GH | 26.56602763823091 | 2.937412284992731 |  |  |  |
| 2021-01-14 13:00:00 | 189725FT | 26.56602763823091 | 2.937412284992731 |  |  |  |
| 2021-01-14 13:52:07 | 123456ABC | 27.03312220493411 | 2.6008171450629343 | 00:52:07 | 39.5 | 45.4 |
| 2021-01-14 14:02:27 | 123456ABC | 27.195391148992073 | 2.490953866466876 | 00:06:20 | 13.2 | 76.6 |

This is over a very large number of rows, at the moment the data is only in day tables with each table containing 1 day. This may however be merged to run this query over multiple days. I am interested in any vehicles exceeding a certain speed so filtering on this column would be great.

Thanks in advance you very clever people. :)

This data is in a MariaDB (10.3)(database but can be exported to anything to help me achieve this.
I have no idea where to start with this and have tried to run this in Power BI with measures which had some partial success but ran out of RAM and having spent a few days trying I have now almost given up on this.

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to MySQL and whilst I can get away with basic commands, I have never attempted anything like this and not even sure if it is possible? Any help or guidance appreciated.

Comment: Forgot to add (as the crow flies) Haversine (great circle) distance is fine, does not need to be by road, this is only to get averages and does not have to be incredibly accurate.

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: what does `select version();` say?

Comment: assuming 10.2 or higher, you would use https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lag/ for this

Comment: Luckily, there is an edit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like:

```
select dt, veh_id, lat, lon, sec_to_time(secs) time, round(distance,1) distance, round(if(secs,distance/secs*3600,0),1) speed
from (
    select dt, veh_id, lat, lon,
        timediff(dt,coalesce(lag(dt) over w,dt)) secs,
        coalesce(
            (3958.7613*(2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(((lat-lag(lat) over w)*0.017453293)/2),2)+COS(lat*0.017453293)*COS((lag(lat) over w)*0.017453293)*POWER(SIN(((lon-lag(lon) over w)*0.017453293)/2),2)))))
        ,0) distance
    from a_large_table
    window w as (partition by veh_id order by dt)
) add_lag;
```

I may have gotten the distance formula wrong, I didn't get the same numbers you did.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=c669be2bff3fcd9a1606a1eee0ffb956)

Comment: MySQL has had ST_Distance_Sphere since 5.7

Comment: @Strawberry but AIUI mariadb does not (but likely will in 10.6)

Comment: This takes 30 minutes to run on my fairly large dataset but does exactly as requested. Thank you, this works.